# Why won't my Strings from Firebase show on myRecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

My Database is like this and I've added to strings under a push() key. The problem is when I add it to my ArrayList it doesn't show anything in my RecyclerView.

This is how I entered the strings into my Database,

```
mToFreezer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("itemInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String name = prefs.getString("Name1", null);
                String date = prefs.getString("Date1", null);


            HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
            dataMap.put("Name", name);
            dataMap.put("Date", date);

            mDatabase.push().setValue(dataMap);
```

Then I retrieved it in another Activity by,

```
public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public ArrayList<Event> mDataSet;
    public Button AddFreezerItems;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

// OnCreate

mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreezerItems");
    String mGroupId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FreezerInventoryRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(mDataSet);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    AddFreezerItems = findViewById(R.id.addItemsFreezer);


    mDatabase.child(mGroupId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String,String>) child.getValue();
                if (value != null) {
                    String name = value.get("name");
                    String date = value.get("date");
                    mDataSet.add(new Event(name,date,null));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have tried everything from putting the data as an ArrayList into Firebase and retrieving it using `GenericTypeIndicator`, and anything else I could find

> UPDATE My Adapter

```
    public class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Event> mDataSet;

    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Event> mDataset){
        this.mDataSet = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row_inventory, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Event product = mDataSet.get(position);
        holder.mItemName.setText(product.getName());
        holder.mItemDate.setText(product.getDate());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mItemName;
        private TextView mItemDate;

        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemNameTxtView);
            mItemDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expirationDateTxtView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us your adapter code?

Comment: I updated it, check it out @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: checkout the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this from you onCreate method:

```
String mGroupId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
```

And call your event listener like this:

```
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
```

I reckon you were listening to the wrong location. Your database already points to the list of FreezerItems:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreezerItems");
```

When you added a `child(mGroupId)` to the reference you're pointing to an inexisting referemce because `mGroupId` was just generated for you.

**EDIT:**

When you do this `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` you're getting the fields of the recenty added object:

```
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String,String>) child.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                String name = value.get("name");
                String date = value.get("date");
                mDataSet.add(new Event(name,date,null));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

Try doing like this:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String,String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (value != null) {
                    String name = value.get("name");
                    String date = value.get("date");
                    mDataSet.add(new Event(name,date,null));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I've got it Thank you I also had to change my Hashmap because it cannot be casted to string

Comment: Awn yeah, didn't see that. It should be HashMap<String, Object> :) Glad i could help

Comment: hey I've changed it to object but it says incompatible type in the String name = value.get(""). would you possibly know a fix for this?

Comment: if you're sure it's a string you can simply cast to string (String)value.get(""). That's because it's now returning an Object

Comment: Ive updated my Hashmaps to <String, Object> and changed it to (String ) value.get(""). But it says again that Strings cannot be cast to Hashmap

Comment: this is not working? String name = (String)value.get("name");

Comment: It is but it just gives me the same error as before String cannot be cast to Hashmap even though I changed it to HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String,Object>) child.getValue();

Comment: I know a way that works like it shows rows in my recycler view but my TextViews are empty

Comment: nevermind THANK YOU VERYMUCH, I J just had to change the "name" and "date" to capital letters because of my database.